# How to get all countries language code in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to create a select language(all countries) drop-down and for this I need all countries language code.

Basically, I need to store language code(for example cn (chinees)) into database from admin page and on front end I am using below code:

```
<script>
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
            pageLanguage: 'en',
            layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
        }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</script>
```

I want to make it dynamic so i need select dropdown on admin page with all countries language code.

Note: I don't want translate admin page it is only to store language code. translation will be only in frontend.

Comment: If you want to store it in a database, listen to changes to the value and then make an AJAX request to the server to store the updated value in the DB.

Comment: No, I will store language code only selected by user.

Comment: generally I need a select language dropdown with options from google API

Comment: Retrieve language list from api then display the list so that the user can choose from the list, 
languages selected will be saved on your db.  

Then compare the language list value from the api to your user's language list stored in db, 

For easier updating of language list when the user modified his preferred language, 

you can just delete all language in the db and insert languages currently selected by the user. So that you would not need to make any comparison anymore.

Comment: Yes but problem is how to get all language codes to display in admin section?

Comment: I am not saving all language codes into database, I just want to get all those to display